# My Laptop is a lot slower after upgrading my ram

Tags: laptop, memory

My laptop is extremely slow after I upgraded with the ram from 8gb to 32gb. This is the laptop :https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07HZGDK8N/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1
And this is the ram: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01BGZEVHU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_image?ie=UTF8&psc=1
I have no idea what's going to because I thought it would be a lot faster.

Comment: What system is it running? You might want to add that to the question.

Comment: Are you sure it is specified for 32 GB of memory?  The highest I could find was 16 GB.  That may be why it is running slow. That or third party (not Dell) memory

Comment: Have you correctly linked to the RAM you have bought? (Clock speed), does it register the full 32GB? When looking at the Intel specs for the CPU of the device you have specified it shows 2400MHz as the highest clock speed for DDR4, the chipset will accept upto 64GB this is also dependent on the motherboard. Information from https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149088/intel-core-i5-8265u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html

Answer (score 1):

If I have the correct device https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-14-5482-2-in-1-laptop_users-guide_en-us.pdf it shows a maximum memory capacity of 16GB.

[image]

Try removing one of the SODIMM devices.